# Why is the item that exists in the CheckedListBox not found via IndexOf()?

Tags: c#, indexof, checkedlistbox, listboxitems

I have this code:

```
if (currentWeekSaved)
{
    DateTime currentWeek = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedValue);
    AssignmentHistory ah = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.WeekOfAssignment == currentWeek && i.TalkType == BIBLE_READING_TALK_TYPE);
    if (ah != null)
    {
        var assignedStudentFirstname = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetStudentFirstNameForID(ah.StudentID_FK);
        var assignedStudentLastname = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetStudentLastNameForID(ah.StudentID_FK);
        assignedStudent = new Student() {FirstName = assignedStudentFirstname, LastName = assignedStudentLastname, StudentID = ah.StudentID_FK};
    }
}
List<Student> BRStudents =
    AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList.Where(h => h.EnrolledInAYttFM)
        .Where(i => i.RecommendedNextTalkTypeID.Equals(BIBLE_READING_TALK_TYPE))
        .OrderBy(j => j.WeekOfLastAssignment)
        .ToList();
if (null != assignedStudent)
{
    // If exists in list, remove it first, and then add it back at the top
    //int assignedStudentIndex = BRStudents.IndexOf(assignedStudent);
    int assignedStudentIndex = checkedListBoxBR.Items.IndexOf(assignedStudent.FullName);
    if (assignedStudentIndex > -1)
    {
        BRStudents.RemoveAt(assignedStudentIndex);
    }
    BRStudents.Insert(0, assignedStudent);
}
checkedListBoxBR.DataSource = BRStudents;
checkedListBoxBR.DisplayMember = "FullName";
checkedListBoxBR.ValueMember = "StudentID";
```

If there is already someone assigned for the week being processed, I want to first remove them from checkedListBoxBR and then add them back at index 0. However, even when the person *is* in checkedListBoxBR, this line:

```
int assignedStudentIndex = 
    checkedListBoxBR.Items.IndexOf(assignedStudent.FullName);
```

...fails to find them. The value of "assignedStudent.FullName" does equal the value of one of the items; as seen above, "FullName" is the ValueMember for CheckedListBox:

On stepping through it, the list of students, BRStudents, has 2 members, the person already assigned and another person; "assignedStudent" is the person already assigned; checkedListBoxBR has three items, the person already assigned plus *two* others.

So why is assignedStudentIndex -1 when the person assigned is represented in FullName? It's true that I don't explicitly assign FullName in this line:

```
assignedStudent = new Student() {FirstName = assignedStudentFirstname, LastName = assignedStudentLastname, StudentID = ah.StudentID_FK};
```

...but FullName is a calculated field in the class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    . . .
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    . . .
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
        }
        set { } 
    }
}
```

So why in tarnation is "So and So" not found in the CheckedListBox's items when it is most decidedly there?

### UPDATE

Olivier's suggestion seems good ("iterate through checkedListBoxBR.Items and see if you find a match between the item's DisplayMember and the assignedStudent.FullName"). But how? I thought maybe something like this would do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxBR.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if checkedListBoxBR.Items[0].DisplayMember.Equals(assignedStudent.FullName)
    {
        checkedListBoxBR.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

...but "DisplayMember" is not recognized here (nor is "RemoveAt").

### UPDATE 2

Responding to Olivier's nudgings, I fixed the above to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxBR.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if checkedListBoxBR.Items[i].DisplayMember.Equals(assignedStudent.FullName)
    {
        checkedListBoxBR.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

...but it still considers DisplayMember to be property-non-grata.

### UPDATE 3

I have simplified the code, and it's working pretty well. Here is the simplified version:

```
// Called whenever the week changes (a new week is navigated to/selected in the combobox)
private void PopulateBibleReadingComboBox()
{
    int BIBLE_READING_TALK_TYPE = 1;
    Student assignedStudent = null;
    List<Student> assignedStudents = null;

    // If the week has been saved, get the student who has been assigned the Bible Reading
    if (currentWeekSaved)
    {
        DateTime currentWeek = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedValue);
        AssignmentHistory ah = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.WeekOfAssignment == currentWeek && i.TalkType == BIBLE_READING_TALK_TYPE);
        if (ah != null)
        {
            var assignedStudentFirstname = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetStudentFirstNameForID(ah.StudentID_FK);
            var assignedStudentLastname = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetStudentLastNameForID(ah.StudentID_FK);
            assignedStudent = new Student() {FirstName = assignedStudentFirstname, LastName = assignedStudentLastname, StudentID = ah.StudentID_FK};
            // Use the ID to get the student and put him/her in a 1-person list (needed for
            // the subsequent LINQ Union)
            assignedStudents =
                AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList.Where(i => i.StudentID == ah.StudentID_FK).ToList();
        }
    }
    // Get all the candidates for assignment
    List<Student> BRStudents =
    AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList.Where(h => h.EnrolledInAYttFM)
        .Where(i => i.RecommendedNextTalkTypeID.Equals(BIBLE_READING_TALK_TYPE))
        .OrderBy(j => j.WeekOfLastAssignment)
        .ToList();
    if (null != assignedStudent) 
    {
        List<Student> allBRStudents = assignedStudents.Union(BRStudents).ToList();
        checkedListBoxBR.DataSource = allBRStudents;
        checkedListBoxBR.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        checkedListBoxBR.ValueMember = "StudentID";
    }
    else // No assigned student found, bind to the candidate students only
    {
        checkedListBoxBR.DataSource = BRStudents;
        checkedListBoxBR.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        checkedListBoxBR.ValueMember = "StudentID";
    }
    // In either case, highlight and check the first one now
    checkedListBoxBR.SelectedIndex = 0;
    checkedListBoxBR.SetItemChecked(0, true);
}
```

Comment: This might be because IndexOf requires an object as you are binding it to BRStudents.

Comment: Within the loop: 'checkedListBoxBR.Items[i]'. Index i instead of 0. And apply removeAt to checkedListBoxBR.Items.

Comment: I have not worked extensively with Windows Forms, but try `checkedListBoxBR.Items[i].ToString() == assignedStudent.FullName`

Comment: DisplayMember is no property of student. Cast to Student and use FullName.

Comment: @GeorgJung: Okay, I'll try this tonight: 
if (Student)checkedListBoxBR.Items[i].FullName.Equals(assignedStudent.FullName)

Comment: You need to add brackets around the expression before `.FullName`

Comment: Do you mean the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two things wrong.

First, you populate `checkedListBoxBR` *after* you check for the presence of a certain item.

Secondly, you are comparing apples and oranges. `checkedListBoxBR.Items` is a Collection of objects, and you are comparing that to a string (`assignedStudent.FullName`) via indexOf. That will not work.

A better solution would be to iterate through `checkedListBoxBR.Items` and see if you find a match between the item's `DisplayMember` and the `assignedStudent.FullName`.

Or you could use a Student object in the the indexOf call, but then you need to make sure you implement IEquatable, override Equals, GetHashCode, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The items of your `checkedListBoxBR` are of type `Student`, because the items in your DataSource are of type `Student`:

```
List<Student> BRStudents = [...]
checkedListBoxBR.DataSource = BRStudents;
```

By using the `IndexOf` function with a string (`Student.FullName`) as a parameter, you are comparing many `Student` objects to one string. No `Student` is equal to your string so you get the result of -1. Try modifing your code like this:

```
int assignedStudentIndex = checkedListBoxBR.Items.IndexOf(assignedStudent);
```

Additionally you might want to [override the `Equals` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.85).aspx).

**Edit**:
As @olivier-de-meulder correctly pointed out you need to move these lines above your lookup to make any option work:

```
checkedListBoxBR.DataSource = BRStudents;
checkedListBoxBR.DisplayMember = "FullName";
checkedListBoxBR.ValueMember = "StudentID";
```